# How to allow the user to scroll a list continuously?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div container with a scroll overflow. It contains a number of child elements in it which scroll like a list. Once the user scrolls all the way to the bottom, I want the top items of the list to re-emerge from the bottom as if it is a continuous, infinite list but with the same items.

The reason is that the list contains links which get highlighted once they are in the vertical center of the page. I want an unending list so that all the items can be highlighted.

I couldn't find any examples or references which helped in my case. Any help would be highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an out-of-the-box way to do this with pure JS (and I haven't heard of any libraries for this either).

However, you could manually listen for the `onscroll` event and then calculate which elements from the top must be removed and appended back at the bottom of the list via `container.appendChild()` and `container.removeChild()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
<div class="Parent-Wrapper">
<div class="Child-Wrapper">
 <a href="">Link 1</a>
 <a href="">Link 2</a>
 <a href="">Link 3</a>
 <a href="">Link 4</a>
</div>
<div class="Child-Wrapper">
 <a href="">Link 5</a>
 <a href="">Link 6</a>
 <a href="">Link 7</a>
 <a href="">Link 8</a>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function(){
var FirstChildDiv  = $('.Child-Wrapper:eq(1)').html();
//Remove First Element
$('.Child-Wrapper:eq(1)').remove();
//Append Removed Element To Next Occuring In Parent Div
$('.Parent-Wrapper').append(FirstChildDiv);
// Thats It.
},5000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: This seems good. I'll try this and accept the answer if it works.